# Sql YEAR(),MONTH() in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've been looking for a few days to resolve the sql query on linq.
This is my sql query ([Date] have format datatime2):

```sql
SELECT [Date], TestingValues 
FROM [SalesValue].[dbo].[TestTable] 
WHERE CONCAT(DATEPART(yyyy,[Date]),DATEPART(MM,[Date])) = '201801'
```

My query looks like this and I can not move on. I do not know how to get a year and a month from b_TestTable.Date:

```csharp
string dat = DateTime.ParseExact(dats, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyyMM");

var testQuery = (
        from b_TestTable in repos.GetTable<TestTable>() 
        where b_TestTable.Date == dat 
        select b_TestTable.TestingValues)
    .ToArray();
```

Can anyone help me how would the query look like in linq ??
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you want to compare against a year/month part of a date or do you want to format it in yyyymo format? If you want to format it, have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings , if not, try b_TestTable.Date.Year & b_TestTable.Date.Month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
var dat = DateTime.ParseExact(dats, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

var testQuery = (
        from b_TestTable in repos.GetTable<TestTable>() 
        where b_TestTable.Date.Year == dats.Year 
            && b_TestTable.Date.Month == dats.Month 
        select b_TestTable.TestingValues)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something obvious here, you only want to check the year and month - so:

```
var dat = DateTime.ParseExact(dats, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var testQuery = (
    from b_TestTable in repos.GetTable<TestTable>() 
    where b_TestTable.Date.Year == dat.Year && b_TestTable.Date.Month == dat.Month
    select b_TestTable.TestingValues)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: `dats` is a string here (did the same mistake)

Comment: Thanks, fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

b_TestTable.Date is of type Date then you do not need to convert dats to string

```
var testQuery = (
        from b_TestTable in repos.GetTable<TestTable>() 
        where b_TestTable.Date.ToString("yyyyMM") == dats//If  is in format yyyyMM
        select b_TestTable.TestingValues)
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to compare dates then you can directly compare month and the year

```
var testQuery = (
            from b_TestTable in repos.GetTable<TestTable>() 
            where b_TestTable.Date.Month == dat.Month && b_TestTable.Date.Year = dat.Month
            select b_TestTable.TestingValues)
        .ToArray();
```

Implementation using Extension methods:

```
repos.GetTable<TestTable>()
.Where(b_TestTable=> b_TestTable.Date.Month == dat.Month && b_TestTable.Date.Year = dat.Month)
.Select(result=> result.TestingValues).ToArray();
```